# Is there a way to dynamically change the size of a widget?

Tags: android

Is there a way to dynamically change the size of a widget?

Can an app have multiple widgets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1. No, sorry.
2. Yes, definitely, you just have to define as many app widget providers
as you need.
```

Answer (score 1):

Resizing widgets on the home-screen dynamically was added in Android 3.1. It is possible now.

Answer (score 0):

App can have multiple widgets. 
what do you mean by changing the size? Are referring to number of cells it can occupy in landscape and portrait?
[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) is a guideline on designing.